# Does Rust offer a package to perform blackbox testing with arbitrary values?

Tags: rust

There is a Go package called [quick](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/quick/) that lets you create a function that returns a boolean and call that function with arbitrary values for each of its parameters, running it for the specified number of iterations.

As an example, it looks like this:

```golang
func TestOddMultipleOfThree(t *testing.T) {
    f := func(x int) bool {
        y := OddMultipleOfThree(x)
        return y%2 == 1 && y%3 == 0
    }
    if err := quick.Check(f, config); err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
    }
}
```

Does Rust offer something similar? I have a few Rust functions that I want to test for many iterations using different arbitrary values each time, and not worry about giving the values myself or complicate stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the [`quickcheck`](https://crates.io/crates/quickcheck) crate.

Comment: I don't know about that, but `quickcheck` seems to be the most direct equivalent.